# can't refer my pagereference methods from my testclass

Tags: apex, class, unit-test

--------------------------------------------class-------------------------------------------

```
Public class OppExtension {

    private final Opportunity opt;
    public list<BucketRate__c> lstWrapper {get;set;} 
    public list<integer> lststrings {get;set;}
    public string selected{get;set;} 
    private  ApexPages.StandardController stdController;
    public boolean DollarFlag{get;set;} 
    public boolean nonDollarFlag{get;set;} 



     public void handleDollar()
     {
       if(opt.Funding_Type__c=='$'){
       DollarFlag=true;
       nonDollarFlag=false;

       }
     else{

     DollarFlag=false;
       nonDollarFlag=true;

     }
     }
    public OppExtension (ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
       this.stdController=stdController;

    // The extension constructor initializes the private member
    // variable acct by using the getRecord method from the standard
    // controller.;
        this.opt= (Opportunity )stdController.getRecord();
        if(opt!=null){
        this.lstWrapper = [select Level_Name__c,High_Days__c,Low_Days__c, Level_Fee__c,Opportunity__c  from BucketRate__c 
                          where Opportunity__c =:opt.id];
       selected=lstWrapper.size()!=0?lstWrapper.size()+'':'0' ;  
        DollarFlag=true;
        nonDollarFlag=false;                  
        }

        else{                
       this.lstWrapper =new list<BucketRate__c>();  

        selected='1';   
        }  

        if(selected=='1'){

         BucketRate__c oWrapp = new BucketRate__c();
      oWrapp.Level_Name__c='Level'+1; 
      //  oWrapp.High_Days__c= 1; 
        //oWrapp.Low_Days__c=0;
       // oWrapp.Level_Fee__c=6;  
        lstWrapper.add(oWrapp);

        }



    }


    public PageReference fetchBucketRating() {

       //Assign your own data to do this. for testing I just placed the dummy data.

       //Test Data
        lstWrapper= new list<BucketRate__c>(); 
        integer k=Integer.valueOf(selected);
        integer v=10;
        integer samp;
        for(integer i=1;i<=k;i++)
        {
         BucketRate__c oWrapp = new BucketRate__c();
        oWrapp.Level_Name__c='Level'+i; 
       /* oWrapp.High_Days__c= 1; 
        oWrapp.Low_Days__c=3;
        oWrapp.Level_Fee__c=6;*/
       /* if(i==1)
        {
        oWrapp.Low_Days__c=0;
        }*/
        /*if(i>1)
        {
         oWrapp.Low_Days__c= samp+1;
         }
         oWrapp.High_Days__c=samp;*/
        oWrapp.Level_Fee__c=null;
        lstWrapper.add(oWrapp); 
        }

        system.debug(selected);
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference save() {
          system.debug(this.opt);

        //this.stdController.save();
       insert opt;

        for(BucketRate__c  br :lstWrapper)
        {
         br.Opportunity__c =this.opt.id;
        }
        insert lstWrapper;
        PageReference newPage = New PageReference('/'+this.opt.id);
        newPage.getParameters().put('id',ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
        newPage.setRedirect(true);
        return newPage;
    }

    public PageReference pdf() {

            PageReference newocp = new PageReference('/apex/asa?Id='+this.opt.Id);
            newocp.setRedirect(true);
            return newocp;
            }

   }
```

------------------------------test class--------------------------------------------------

```
@istest
public class OppExtensionTest
{
public static testMethod void oppExtensionTest() 
{

account acc= new account();
acc.name='account1';
insert acc;
account acc1= [select id,name from account where name= 'account1'];


PageReference testPage = new pagereference('/apex/asa');
    testPage.getParameters().put('id', 'opp.id');

    Test.setCurrentPage(testPage);


opportunity opp= new opportunity();
opp.name='pradeep';
opp.accountid= acc1.id;
opp.closedate= date.parse('12/12/12');
opp.StageName='credit approved';
 opp.Funding_Type__c='$';

insert opp;

 ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(opp);
    OppExtension e = new OppExtension (sc);

    e.handleDollar();
     opp.Funding_Type__c='rs';
      e.handleDollar();
    e.selected='3';
    e.fetchBucketRating();


}
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little? It's hard to tell what your issue is. It always pays to be as specific as possible.

Comment: i have already written the test class but i am achiving only 64% code coverage i am not covering mu pagereferences in my class like save();pdf().. ia m not getting how to achive it

Comment: Have you tried to call the those methods from your test class? If so can please update the post with that code?

Comment: You can just call them on the controller instance and check the returned values have the URL you expect or that they're not null etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since these are most likely called outside of your class, and probably by a visualforce page, you'll have to invoke the classes in your test class.

The best practice for this is to create a separate test method for each method you'd like to test, and then you can call System.asserts to determine the outcome of the method. See my example below:

```
static testmethod void testSave(){
    //Insert your mock data here
    //Construct your pagereference

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(opp);
    OppExtension e = new OppExtension (sc);

    Test.startTest();
    PageReference pageRef = e.Save();
    Test.stopTest();

    //Adjust these asserts for your code.
    System.assertEquals('expectedUrl',pageRef.getUrl());
    Map<String,String> parms = pageRef.getParameters();
    System.assertEquals(expectedNumParameters,pageRef.values().size());
    System.assertEquals('expectedVal',parms.get('paramkey));

    //Also, assert that the opportunity and any other records were modified as you expected   
}

static testmethod void testPdf(){
    //Insert your mock data here
    //Construct your pagereference

    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(opp);
    OppExtension e = new OppExtension (sc);

    Test.startTest();
    PageReference pageRef = e.pdf();
    Test.stopTest();

    //Adjust these asserts for your code.
    System.assertEquals('expectedUrl',pageRef.getUrl());
    Map<String,String> parms = pageRef.getParameters();
    System.assertEquals(expectedNumParameters,pageRef.values().size());
    System.assertEquals('expectedVal',parms.get('paramkey));
    System.assertEquals('expectedBody',parms.getBody());

    //Also, assert that the opportunity and any other records were modified as you expected   
}
```

Another (minor) issue is that you're not setting the correct opportunity id.  You are currently setting it to an arbitrary string rather than an actual id of an opportunity.  Instead, move the page reference below your opportunity insert, and set the opportunity's id instead of the string 'opp.id'.

```
//Move this above your PageReference declaration!
opportunity opp= new opportunity();
opp.name='pradeep';
opp.accountid= acc1.id;
opp.closedate= date.parse('12/12/12');
opp.StageName='credit approved';
 opp.Funding_Type__c='$';

insert opp;

//This needs to happen after the opp insert...
PageReference testPage = new pagereference('/apex/asa');
//change the following to opp.id instead of 'opp.id'
testPage.getParameters().put('id',opp.id);

Test.setCurrentPage(testPage);
```